# awkward behaviour in bash find-loop with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, docker, while-loop, ffmpeg, find

There is something weird going on when running following script with Docker.

The dockerfile for this is:

```
FROM debian:9
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install ffmpeg curl
COPY . /app
```

The script `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /pfs/in -maxdepth 1 -name "*.flac" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' inFile; do
    echo "\n##### Process '${inFile}' #####"
    ffmpeg -y -i ${inFile} -ar 16000 tmp.wav # use 16kHz - default for EML
done
```

Starting this, when mounting 3 files into the container:

```
$ ls pfs/in/
Testaudio16k_2.flac  Testaudio16k.flac  Testaudio16k.wav  TestSprache_Saetze.flac
$ docker run --rm -t -v $(pwd)/pfs/in:/pfs/in test-img:latest /bin/bash run.sh
```

I get an error on processing the second file: `pfs/in/Testaudio16k_2.flac: No such file or directory`. The leading `/` is missing. It is also missing in the preceeding echo. Indeed this happens every **second** file (if I put more than 3 files in that folder).

Now coming to the counter example:
If I comment out the `ffmpeg` line in the script, rebuild and run, The echo prints for every file the correct path.

Does anybody have an idea about this?
Is it about the `find` or is the `ffmpeg`doing something weird? Something completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-nostdin`:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -i input output
```

From the [`ffmpeg` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

> `-stdin`
>   Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless
>   standard input is used as an input. To explicitly disable interaction
>   you need to specify `-nostdin`.
>
> Disabling interaction on standard input is useful, for example, if
>   `ffmpeg` is in the background process group. Roughly the same result
>   can be achieved with `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null` but it requires a shell.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce on a regular Bash console. It's indeed a weird interaction between ffmpeg and the IFS or null delimiter.

This method work as intended

`find ~/tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "*.flac" -print0 | xargs -r0 -i bash -c  'echo {}; ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i {} -ar 16000 tmp.wav'`

For your code, add `< /dev/null` at the end of ffmpeg command as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334759/2834978).

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i {} -ar 16000 tmp.wav < /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce that but I strongly recommend to quote the filename when passing it to ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "${inFile}" -ar 16000 tmp.wav.
```

A space at the beginning or end of the filename would explain your error when you don't use quotes

Btw, you don't need a bash loop. You can just use `find`:

```
docker run --rm -t -v $(pwd)/pfs/in:/pfs/in foo \
    find /pfs/in -maxdepth 1 -name "*.flac" \
      -printf "## Process file %f ##\n" \
      -exec ffmpeg -y -i {} -ar 16000 tmp.wav \;
```

Comment: can't reproduce with Docker? In my host system I also can't reproduce. Further: I need the loop because more commands will be coming.

Comment: Yeah, I created a Docker setup like you described. I'm not saying that you can't use a loop.